# How to prevent AutoCompleteTextView drop down list disappear after user input

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am developing an customized AutoCompleteTextView with customized adapter. However, when the text in the text field changes, the drop down list disappear temporarily until the new results is published. I think what is happening is the AutoCompleteTextView will hide the drop down list during filtering. However, is there a way to force the AutoCompleteTextView to display the drop down list all the time?

Comment: In what Android version are you testing this? At least in 4.4.2 the drop down list remains visible while typing (so long as `enoughToFilter()` returns true, depending on the number of characters entered so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is I didn't actively use the Filter in the customized adapter because the `Filter` doesn't fit my case. If the `performFiltering()` method returns null or the `values` field in the returned `FilterResults` in that method is empty, the drop down list will be hidden. The way I solve my problem is returning a dummy FilterResults object and fill dummy `values` field in the object in `performFiltering()` method.